# ISBLANK returns neither true or false

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 important columns
Destination Name is a custom column with a LOOKUPVALUE function. Which should return either a value, or BLANK. It is correctly returning these.

The second column, titled Column, is a custom column with an ISBLANK function which should return To Staff, or From Staff (True or False). depending on if the Destination Name is blank or not. It is returning True, False correctly, however, I am also getting several hundred blank rows. This is the same if using IF(Destination Name = "")

Using ISBLANK on Column, all of the blank rows are not recognised as being blank, which makes me believe they are an error. No documentation says what would make ISBLANK return an error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Dom

Comment: I think it makes sense to post the formula as formatted code in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your source column, probably you have blank and null (empty) value in the column, and null is evaluated to null (visible blank in your results);

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue!

I didn't realise Lookupvalue would pass on a null value